# Issue with Handling Background Tasks in Streamlit

Tags: python, python-3.x, streamlit

I'm building a Streamlit app that involves running a time-consuming task in the background when a "push 1" is clicked.

However, I'm facing issues with the execution flow:
if I use "push 1" than "push 2", "push 2" give result like "push 1"+"push 2"
if I use "push 2" than result correct.

I tried different keys. it seems not work
without "while True" it work, but I need loop for taking data in real time from device

what can be reason for this? and how fix it?

Here's a simplified version of the code I'm using:

```
import streamlit as st
import time


if st.button(' Push 1 ', key=1):
    with st.spinner("wait Push 1"):
        time.sleep(1)
        st.success('Push 1')

if st.button(' Push 2', key=2):
    st.success('Push 2')

while True:
    pass
```